# how can i update my progress bar step by step?

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, swift3, dispatch-async

i have code where i add one constant every second to my array, how can i update my progress bar every second when array is changed?

```
var array: [Int] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        upgradeArray()
    }

    func upgradeArray() {
        for i in 0...10 {
            sleep(1)
            array.append(i)
            print(i)
            let percentProgress = Float(Float(self.array.count)*100.0/10.0)
            progressBar.setProgress(percentProgress, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Comment: i need show to user how base will extracting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done with DispatchQueue.global(priority: .default).async

```
func upgradeArray() {
        for i in 0...10 {
            DispatchQueue.global(priority: .default).async {
                //sleep(1)
                self.array.append(i)
                print(i)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let percentProgress = Float(Float(self.array.count)*100.0/10.0)
                    self.progressBar.setProgress(percentProgress, animated: true)
                })
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: can  help me out two integer value like example first var array: [Int] = [1500]
   & var total = 500 so i want let value = array/total type of output in swift 3.0 using your method

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer.  Assuming your progress view is 0 to 1 and incrementing by 0.1 each second...

```
var timer: Timer?
var array = [String]()

func doStuff() {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in

        self.array.append("foo")

        let change: Float = 0.1
        self.progressView.progress = self.progressView.progress + (change)

        if self.progressView.progress >= 1.0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but if you're already adding objects to an array every second I'm sure you can work that out within the same timer.  If you know how many objects you're adding then you can modify the `change` constant to 1/total number of expected elements.

Comment: i need to insert JSON base of 16000+ arrows to CoreData base